# Why cant we print a variable with html names included in it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to learn ReactJS.

I have a html selections option as 
`<option value="navigate">Navigate to &lt;URL&gt; </option>`

and I have obtained the selected text in my script

`let type = document.getElementById
   ('stepType').options[document.getElementById('stepType').selectedIndex].text;`

when i `console.log(type)` i am getting "Navigate to <URL>"

but when i try to update my div's inner html, all that is getting printed is "Navigate to "

Thanks for putting up with my stupid question, but I would really like to know what is happening underneath, since i know `let type = "Navigate to &lt;URL&gt;"` would work.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid XXS attach React will render text. If you want to render html use

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "Navigate to &lt;URL&gt;"}}/>
```